# inserting file as user input in radare2 (VS shell & VS gdb) (linux)

Tags: shell, debugging, gdb, radare2

I have a file that I want to use as the user input in a C program that ask for user input trough a scanf  (playing and **learning** in linux)

lets call the program **a.ou**t and the file with the contents **myImput**, thereby:

- in shell  I can go:    `cat myInput | ./a.out`
- in gdb I could do:    `run < myInput` once loaded with `gdb a.out`

is that possible in radare2 ?
I see how to inject parameters, but not content files as user input

Answer (score 0):

To type input to a program when you debug, follow these instructions:

1. Create a file `profile.r22`
2. Write the content of this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
program=./a.out
input=aaabbbccc
```

where `aaabbbccc` is the content of the file that you want to read

3. Tell to radare2 to use this file to send the previous input with the command: `r2 -d ./a.out -e dbg.profile=profile.rr2`
4. type `dc` in radare2 to launch debugging

You can also do it faster in some commands:

```
{ echo -ne '#!/usr/bin/rarun2\nprogram=./a.out\ninput='; cat myInput; } > profile.rr2;
r2 -d ./a.out -e dbg.profile=profile.rr2
```

And then still launch the command `dc`.